# Probability of at least one triangle in Erdos-Renyi graph

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, random-graphs

Cross-posting here as I didn't get a satisfactory solution on cv.

This is a well-known problem in random graph theory, where we show that if $X$ is the number of triangles in $G(V,E,p)$ with $p=\omega(\frac{1}{n})$, we can show that 
$$
P(X \geq 1) \geq 1-o(\frac{1}{n}) \to_n 1
$$
using Chebyshev inequality and asymptotic expansion of binomial coefficients, $\binom{n}{k} \sim \frac{n^k}{k!}$.

What I don't understand is the part where the second moment is used for indicator variables: 
$$
\mathbf{E}X^2 = \mathbf{E} (\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}{3}} X_k)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}{3}} \mathbf{E}X^2_k +\sum_{k \neq j}\mathbf{E}X_k X_j
$$
Specifically, I don't understand the absence of 2 in front of the second sum. The explanation is that triangles are ordered. This means that selecting triangle $X_j$ and then $X_k$ is different to $X_k$ and then $X_j$. Essentially I don't understand why $\mathbf{E}X_k X_j \neq \mathbf{E}X_j X_k$. If I solve it with 2 in front of the sum, I don't get the convergence.

Comment: The meaning of $\sum_{k \neq j}$ is that we sum over the following set of ordered pairs $A:=\{ (j,k) : 1\leq j, k \leq {n \choose 3}, j \neq k\}$. In fact, if $(j,k) \in A$, then $(k,j) \in A$. It is true that $E[X_k X_j] = E[X_j X_k]$ so the summands corresponding to $(j,k)$ and $(k,j)$ are the same. Thus $\sum_{(j,k) \in A} E[X_j X_k] = 2\sum_{j=1}^{{n \choose 3}-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^{{n \choose 3}} E[X_j X_k]$.

Comment: If $p = o(1/n)$, then w.h.p. there are no triangles. Do you want $p$ to be such that $np \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes to the second comment: I mean $p(n)=\omega(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: For the first comment: since $X_k, X_j$ are indicator variables, $\mathbf{E}X_k X_j$ is just $P(X_k X_j)$, or the number of ways to fix the vertices. So I fix 3 vertices for the first triangle and 3 for the second. Is this right?

Comment: So why do I need to count $\mathbf{E} X_k X_j$ and $\mathbf{E} X_j X_k$ separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square of the sum is expanded into a sum of products. Both $\mathbf EX_1X_2$ and $\mathbf EX_2X_1$ occur in the expansion. You can either leave them like that and write $\sum_{k\ne j}$, or you can combine them and write $2\sum_{k\lt j}$, that's just a matter of convenience. What you can't do is write $2\sum_{k\ne j}$, because then you're counting each pair four times, not just twice.